# If Gandalf was a Maia, why couldn't he change form?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf, maiar

According to [The LOTR wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Maiar), Gandalf and Saruman are amongst the named Maiar.

Again, a quote from Wiki:

> Maiar, like Valar, do not array themselves in a fixed form, but can
>   freely change their form.

Sauron was also a Maia (named [Mairon](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Sauron)), which he used his ability to reshape, and called himself Annatar, "the Lord of Gifts".

So, if Gandalf could do the same, why didn't he just transform into a flying creature and escape when he was captured by Saruman and imprisoned on the top of Orthanc?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Why didn't Gandalf carry the ring in Maiar form?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108389) (Again, identical use of quotes)

Comment: I believe the above is justified by [the second answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105197) directly answering this question and linking to the first [linked answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/101983) which also has identical quotes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### The Istari were ordered to remain in, and also stuck in, forms of Men

A description of the Istari is given in the *Unfinished Tales*. They were given their "Men-forms" before departing Valinor, and thereafter remained in these forms.

#### Gandalf and the other Istari

> Emissaries they were from Lords of the West, the Valar, who still took counsel
>   for the governance of Middle-earth, and when the shadow of Sauron began first to stir again took this
>   means of resisting him. For with the consent of Eru they sent members of their own high order, **but clad in
>   bodies of as of Men, real and not feigned**, but subject to the fears and pains and weariness of earth, able
>   to hunger and thirst and be slain; though because of their noble spirits they did not die, and aged only by
>   the cares and labours of many long years.
>
> > "Who would go? For they must be
> >     mighty, peers of Sauron, but must forgo might, and **clothe themselves in flesh so as to treat on equality and
> >     win the trust of Elves and Men**. But this would imperil them, dimming their wisdom and knowledge, and
> >     confusing them with fears, cares, and weariness coming from the flesh."
>
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales*</sub>

How easy would their mission have been if they could have transformed into, say, powerful creatures to take down Sauron's forces? They were stuck in their "Men-forms" because their main purpose was to unite the forces of good against Sauron, not challenge Sauron physically.

> [...]; whereas now their emissaries were forbidden to reveal themselves in forms of majesty, or to seek to rule the wills of Men and Elves by open display of power, **but coming in shapes weak and humble**
>   were bidden to advise and persuade Men and Elves to good, and to seek to unite in love and
>   understanding all those whom Sauron, should he come again, would endeavour to dominate and corrupt.
>
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales*</sub>
>
> They came therefore in the shape of Men, though they were never young and aged only slowly, and they
>   had many powers of mind and hand
>
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings*</sub>

So, to answer your question, Gandalf didn't transform because he couldn't transform. He'd "*clothed himself in flesh*" before leaving Valinor, and remained in flesh till he succeeded in his mission.

#### Sauron

Sauron, on the other hand, was a corrupted Maia, who came to Middle-earth on his own accord (to join Morgoth). He was able to assume a different form in the Second Age because he wasn't ordered (by the Valar) to stay in one form.

Of course, later on in the Downfall of Numenor, he loses his physical body in the wreck, and is therefore stuck in an ugly-as-heck form<sup>1</sup> till he loses this body *again* after the War of the Ring.

[image: Sauron]

---

<sup>1</sup> [Painting of Sauron](http://photobucket.com/gallery/http://s254.photobucket.com/user/visualweasel/media/Sauron.jpg.html), done by JRR Tolkien

Comment: I think the "real be not feigned" quote is very important here. They can't change shape because human bodies can't.

Comment: Good answer, and +1 from having it come from Olórin himself. Straight from the maia's mouth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, is that why saruman couldn't change form even after he sided with the enemy? Simply because he _couldn't_, not because he was ordered _not to_?

Comment: @JackJohansson indeed. They were stuck in their fleshy forms until their Mission was done.

Comment: @Olórin So, now one final question. After saruman turned, there wasn't really any more mission for him to accomplish. I'm confused about this.

Comment: @JackJohansson to start off, the Istari were clothed in flesh sometime upon accepting their Mission in Valinor. They left Valinor for ME. Until their Mission was completed or the Valar allowed, they were stuck in their forms.

Comment: @Olórin Thanks. I was curious to figure whether saruman couldn't change under any circumstances (including death), or Tolkien cheated about this to keep the middle-earth safe :)

Comment: @MatCauthon Wait does that mean that Saruman would rather rule over Middle-earth stuck in his old-man form, weaker, than live amongst his kin with all his powers? "Rule in hell vs serve in heaven"?

Comment: @Parrotmaster Probably doesn't like being bossed around by ol' Aulë in Valinor. "Curumo, pass me thee hammer!"

Comment: @Parrotmaster Basically, yes. Another quote from the essay "The Istari": "..., and though they knew whence they came the memory of the Blessed Realm was to them a vision from afar off, for which (so long as they remained true to their mission) they yearned exceedingly."

Comment: I'm not sure Sauron was trapped in a particular form by order of the Valar, so much as by the direct intervention of Eru.

Comment: Painting of Sauron [crushing the heads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t4pmlHRokg) of Middle Earth.